# Google Maps, dúvida sobre sobreposição de raio de marcadores

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Implementei a API v3 do Google Maps em Javascript em um sistema de reservas, no sistema utilizei PHP para conectar ao banco de dados MySQL para retornar as unidades de uma franqueadora que já existem e estão operando, e também disponibilizei na mesma tela um campo de pesquisa para a consulta de endereços para verificar se no endereço já existe ou não uma unidade franqueada em um raio de 1.500 metros, até aí tudo bem, as franqueadas em funcionamento tem um raio de 1.500 metros de cor branca, e os endereços cadastrados como reservas tem o raio de 1.500 metros na cor verde, mas surgiu uma necessidade, a de quando uma reserva sobrepor o raio de uma franqueada existente em funcionamento, ter a cor do raio alterada de verde para vermelho para sinalizar a sobreposição.

A tela exibe as franqueadas operando com seu raio, as reservas com seu raio, está funcionando perfeitamente, porém consultei a documentação da API do Google Maps e por ser extensa talvez não encontrei ou não sei se disponibilizam este recurso, gostaria da ajuda da comunidade para sanar essa dúvida, se é possível alterar a cor do raio de um marcador sobreposto, e se sim, se existe um exemplo de alguém que já o fez. Segue abaixo a imagem do atual:

[image: GOOGLE MAPS E MARCADORES DE FRANQUEADAS ATIVAS E RESERVA DE ENDEREÇOS PARA NOVAS FRANQUEADAS]

Existe a integração padrão, as marcações de raio verde é uma "var location" apenas de reservas, e outra "var location" somente de locais que já estão em funcionamento. preciso ver como alterar a cor do "var location" dos raios verdes quando estão sobrepostos com os de raio branco.

O código escrito segue. O código inclui a pesquisa de endereço, o mapa, os marcadores e o código de integração da API:

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-xI/qyl9vpwWFOXz7+x/9WkG5j/SVnSw21viy8fWwbeE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var marker;
        var image = 'https://www.crosslife.info/painel/assets/images/mark-teste.png';

        var locations2 = [

            ['RESERVA: ', -23.9446791, -46.3264323, 'Av. Senador Feijó, 421 - Vila Nova, Santos - SP, 11013-162, Brasil'],
['RESERVA: ', , , 'R. Assunção, 414 - Sion, Belo Horizonte - MG, 30320-040, Brasil'],
['RESERVA: ', , , 'R. Padre Feijó, 373 - Vila Tiberio, Ribeirão Preto - SP, 14050-360, Brasil'],
['RESERVA: ', , , 'R. Vitoriano Salut, 72 - Chácara Belvedere, Indaiatuba - SP, Brasil'],
['RESERVA: ', -20.8873894, -47.5997438, 'Rua Ana Luiza, 197 - Bairro Castelo, Batatais - SP, 14300-000, Brasil']

        ]


        var locations = [
            ['Vila Osasco', -23.544559, -46.781034, 'Avenida Santo Antônio, 2761, Vila Osasco,  - SP, 06083-215, Brasil'],
['Rebouças', -22.8904057, -43.5603237, 'Avenida Rebouças, 3657, Centro,  - SP, 13170-023, Brasil'],
['Nutrition Bauru', -22.3370765, -49.0891827, 'Avenida Castelo Branco, 7-15, Vila Independência,  - SP, 17052-000, Brasil'],
['Pitangueiras', -23.2022764, -46.8836439, 'Rua Pitangueiras, 790, Jardim Pitangueiras,  - SP, 13206-716, Brasil'],
['Nutrition Vale do Sol', -20.4229151, -49.9592271, 'Avenida pansani, 3092, Vale do sol,  - SP, 15500-302, Brasil'],
['Cidade Nova Montes Claros-Mg', -16.739527, -43.8653989, 'Avenida Dona Gregória, 101, Cidade Nova,  - MG, 39400-464, Brasil'],
['Centro Salto', -23.199741, -47.3008818, 'Avenida Dom Pedro II, 1421, Centro,  - SP, 13320-241, Brasil'],
['ASSIS', -22.6575047, -50.397561, 'Rua Antônio da Silva Cunha Bueno, 425, Jardim Paulista,  - SP, 19815-080, Brasil'],
['Paulinia', -22.743178, -47.1744984, 'Avenida João Aranha, 946, Alto de Pinheiros,  - SP, 13145-256, Brasil'],
['SBC Centro', -23.7132318, -46.5532384, 'Rua Joaquim Nabuco, 56, Centro,  - SP, 09720-375, Brasil'],
['- Chácara', -23.6290144, -46.7025941, 'Rua da paz, 1498, Chácara Santo Antônio,  - SP, 04713-000, Brasil'],
['Nova Europa', -22.9424831, -47.0573369, 'Avenida Baden Powell, 1831, Nova Europa,  - SP, 13040-093, Brasil'],
['Morada do Sol', -23.1269188, -47.244239, 'Rua João Martini, 475, Jardim Morada do Sol,  - SP, 13348-350, Brasil'],
['campo grande RJ', -22.890374, -43.560187, 'Rua do petróleo, 14, Campo Gande,  - RJ, 23087-125, Brasil'],
['Tremembé', -23.4587589, -46.6149244, 'Avenida Nova Cantareira, 4794, Tucuruvi,  - SP, 02340-002, Brasil'],
['Crosslife Nutrition Vila das Belezas', -23.6491279, -46.7543918, 'Estrada de Itapecerica, 2219, Vila das Belezas,  - SP, 05835-005, Brasil'],
['Centro', -23.0854053, -47.2105986, 'Rua Humaitá, 1099, Centro,  - SP, 13339-140, Brasil'],
['ITAPECERICA', -23.698334, -46.8527042, 'Rua Ari Batalha, 393, Parque Paraiso,  - SP, 06850-335, Brasil'],
['lapa', -23.5250071, -46.6872423, 'Rua Clélia, 911, Lapa,  - SP, 05042-000, Brasil'],
['Cross life', -17.7718674, -48.6186493, 'Rua B-02, S/N, Estância Itanhanga,  - GO, 75690-000, Brasil'],
['Tatuapé', -23.552282, -46.5566401, 'Rua Francisco Marengo, 1717, Tatuapé,  - SP, 03313-001, Brasil'],
['Flamboyant', -22.8762222, -47.0358206, 'Rua Comendador Doutor Antônio Pompeo Camargo, 104, Jardim Boa Esperança,  - SP, 13091-502, Brasil'],
['N.Sr de Fatima', -22.8975439, -47.1685964, 'Armelinda Espúrio da Silva, 565, Jardim Nossa Senhora de Fátima,  - SP, 13084-450, Brasil'],
['Agapeama', -23.2053398, -46.8651296, 'Rua da Varzea Paulista, 487, Vila Agricola,  - SP, 13202-700, Brasil'],
['Buriti', -23.2230818, -46.8760877, 'Rua Dom Pedro I, 462, Jardim Buriti,  - SP, 13225-790, Brasil'],
['BOA VISTA', -14.8793362, -40.832031, 'Avenida Gilenilda Alves, 1345, Boa Vista,  - BA, 45027-560, Brasil'],
['CROSS TRAINING - FABRICA DE RESULTADOS', -23.6008617, -46.8988726, 'Rua Pinhal, 83, Jardim Sabia,  - SP, 06716-575, Brasil'],
['Valentina Cross Life', -16.7287284, -43.8835938, 'Rua Espírito Santo Esplanada, 395, Esplanada,  - MG, 39401-452, Brasil'],
['PEDRO PINHO', -23.5402247, -46.8010548, 'Avenida General Pedro Pinho, 1052, Pestana,  - SP, 06122-160, Brasil'],
['Vicente Pires', -15.8095347, -48.0159685, 'Rua 4 A, 24, Vicente Pires,  - DF, 72006-206, Brasil'],
['Crosslife 9 de Julho', -23.1939338, -47.2850897, 'Avenida 9 de julho, 1733, Vila Roma,  - SP, 13321-560, Brasil'],
['Rr soluções comerciais', -23.6212842, -46.6887282, 'Rua Oscar Gomes Cardim, 37, Vila cordeiro,  - SP, 04580-040, Brasil'],
['Cross Life', -15.8382146, -48.0222926, 'Rua 17 norte, 3, Águas Claras Norte,  - DF, 71910-540, Brasil'],
['Jd.europa', -23.0715471, -47.2270102, 'Alameda José Amstalden, 1173, Jardim Europa,  - SP, 13331-100, Brasil'],
['Colibris', -23.1279811, -47.2494992, 'Guaianazes, 94, Jardim Colibris,  - SP, 13349-820, Brasil'],
['várzea centro', -23.2131507, -46.8458156, 'Avenida José Rabelo Portela, 276, Jardim Maria de Fátima,  - SP, 13220-540, Brasil'],
['CROSS LIVE GUARAPIRANGA', -23.670636, -46.7389666, 'Estrada do M boi Mirim, 609, Jardim das Flores,  - SP, 04905-020, Brasil'],
['Jaguare -SP', -23.5504009, -46.7483687, 'Avenida Presidente Altino, 602, Jaguare,  - SP, 05335-120, Brasil'],
['Cidade Nova', -20.5294527, -47.3930331, 'Rua Frederico Moura, 1650, Cidade Nova,  - SP, 14401-150, Brasil'],
['Consolação', -20.5478245, -47.4040117, 'Rua Chile, 1521, Jardim Consolação,  - SP, 14400-110, Brasil'],
['Piratininga', -20.5421062, -47.3746126, 'Avenida Hugo Betarello, 3580, Piratininga,  - SP, 14403-219, Brasil'],
['Delfino', -16.7419277, -43.8419136, 'Avenida Neco Delfino, 1034, Delfino Magalhães,  - MG, 39402-181, Brasil'],
['Nutrition', -5.8911932, -35.2064656, 'Avenida Maria Lacerda, 8792, Nova Parnamirim,  - RN, 59152-600, Brasil'],
['Avenida São Vicente', -20.5510118, -47.3871382, 'Avenida São Vicente, 3455, Jd. Noêmia,  - SP, 14403-720, Brasil'],
['CrossLife São Luiz - Itu', -23.271317, -47.2831139, 'Rua Gabriel de Bourbon y Bourbon, 45, São Luiz,  - SP, 13304-060, Brasil'],
['Adhemar de Barros', -20.5156199, -47.3729824, 'Avenida Adhemar Pereira de Barros, 301, Jardim Eden,  - SP, 14402-250, Brasil'],
['Santa Inês BH', -19.8862532, -43.9090425, 'Rua Vicente Risola, 660, Santa Inês,  - MG, 31080-160, Brasil'],
['Cross Life', -22.8676863, -47.2244041, 'Avenida Olívio Franceschini, 1900, Parque Ortolândia,  - SP, 13184-160, Brasil'],
['Lopes assessoria esportiva', -22.8384459, -47.1588462, 'Avenida Minasa, 1195, Vila San Martin,  - SP, 13180-165, Brasil'],
['CASSIOPÉIA', -23.2290628, -45.8878066, 'Avenida Cassiopéia, 678, Jardim Satélite,  - SP, 12230-010, Brasil'],
['Unidade Dompieri', -20.5173041, -47.3975326, 'Avenida Orlando Dompieri, 1820, Jardim Barão,  - SP, 14409-003, Brasil'],
['Casa Verde', -23.5117625, -46.6508895, 'Rua Brazelisa Alves de Carvalho, 431, Vila Baruel,  - SP, 02510-030, Brasil'],
['Team - Vila Yara', -23.5459214, -46.7639022, 'Rua Moema, 49, Vila Yara,  - SP, 06028-280, Brasil'],
['Jardim dos Ipês', -23.280734, -47.3069559, 'Avenida Caetano Ruggieri, 4006, Jardim dos Ipês,  - SP, 13311-440, Brasil'],
['Crosslife - Av Brasil', -20.5266837, -47.379848, 'Avenida Brasil, 1262, Vila Aparecida,  - SP, 14401-240, Brasil'],
['Grajaú', -23.7355639, -46.69432, 'Rua Leri Santos, 194, Grajaú,  - SP, 04822-290, Brasil'],
['Aeroporto', -20.5752957, -47.3673357, 'Rua Cyro Eduardo Rosa Faleiros, 1158, Aeroporto 2,  - SP, 14404-091, Brasil'],
['Eloy Chaves', -23.1898838, -46.9623624, 'Rua Doutor Ângelo Pernambuco, 130, Eloy Chaves,  - SP, 13212-123, Brasil'],
['Independência', -16.719114, -43.8253718, 'Rua Lagoa das Palmas, 404, Carmelo,  - MG, 39402-729, Brasil'],
['Guanabara', -22.8896133, -47.0600126, 'Rua Rafael Sampaio, 187, Guanabara,  - SP, 13023-240, Brasil'],
['Nutrition', -22.9240667, -47.081058, 'Rua Manuel Francisco Monteiro, 38, Parque Industrial,  - SP, 13031-500, Brasil'],
['CROSSLIFE NUTRITION', -18.935402, -48.2457239, 'Avenida João Mendes, 631, Pampulha,  - MG, 38408-660, Brasil'],
['Cross Life', -23.5954744, -46.8486695, 'Avenida Elias zarzur, 147, Parque São George,  - SP, 06708-210, Brasil'],
['marajoara', -23.6640911, -46.6872448, 'Rua Roque Giangrande filho, 68, Jardim marajoara,  - SP, 04674-110, Brasil'],
['Valinhos', -22.9623421, -46.9786923, 'Rua Lino Buzatto, 855, Jardim Pinheiros,  - SP, 13274-440, Brasil'],
['nutriton', -5.8005449, -35.203111, 'Rua Joaquim Fagundes, 688, Barro vermelho,  - RN, 59022-500, Brasil'],
['Via Norte', -22.875639, -47.129895, 'Rua Renato Ribeiro, 33, Pq Via Norte,  - SP, 13065-707, Brasil'],
['Campos Elíseos', -22.9292555, -47.1019142, 'Avenida Paulo Provenza Sobrinho, 125, Campos Elíseos,  - SP, 13060-864, Brasil'],
['VILA GUILHERME', -23.5034688, -46.6047706, 'Rua Lagoa Panema, 543, Vila Guilherme,  - SP, 02051-050, Brasil'],
['Itaici', -23.1045439, -47.1825595, 'Av.Coronel Antonio Estanislau do Amaral, 1305, Jardim Juliana,  - SP, 13335-410, Brasil'],
['Meira Junior', -21.1768859, -47.7974337, 'Av. Meira Júnior, 520, Jd Paulusta,  - SP, 14090-003, Brasil'],
['Crosslife Cintra', -16.7296067, -43.8499477, 'Av Coronel Luiz Maia, 616, Cintra,  - MG, 39401-486, Brasil'],
['Casa Verde', -23.5117632, -46.6508951, 'Rua Brazelisa Alves de Carvalho, 431, Casa Verde,  - SP, 02510-030, Brasil'],
['Nutrition', -23.085744, -47.1850339, 'Rua: Antônio Martins Rosa, 24, Vila Homero,  - SP, 13338-740, Brasil'],
['NUTRITION TANCREDAO', -22.9387375, -47.0970644, 'R NELLY BONTORE, 343, JD SANTA AMALIA,  - SP, 13050-114, Brasil'],
['RIO BONITO', -23.6814618, -46.7054199, 'Av. do Rio Bonito, 974, Socorro,  - SP, 04776-001, Brasil'],
['Juiz de Fora', -21.762771, -43.345585, 'Avenida Presidente Itamar Franco, 676, Centro,  - MG, 36010-020, Brasil'],
['Nutrition Jardim do Trevo', -22.9248287, -47.0658387, 'Rua Fernão Pompeo de Camargo, 1079, Jardim do Trevo,  - SP, 13040-010, Brasil'],
['Crosslife Campo Limpo', -23.645127, -46.7638252, 'Estrada do Campo Limpo, 2722, Campo Limpo,  - SP, 05777-000, Brasil'],
['14 de DEZEMBRO', -23.2129867, -46.8745139, 'Av. 14 de Dezembro, 1440, Vila Mafalda,  - SP, 0, Brasil'],
['não tem', -22.7405319, -47.3042479, 'Avenida Geraldo Gobbo, 233, Santa Cruz,  - SP, 13477-410, Brasil'],
['João Dias', -23.6451097, -46.7158278, 'Avenida João Dias, 1601, Santo Amaro,  - SP, 04724-002, Brasil'],
['Plaza Itu-SP', -23.2639438, -47.2790414, 'avenida plaza, 182, jardim paraiso,  - SP, 13302-100, Brasil'],
['PARK', -23.1520141, -46.9211165, 'Av Professor Pedro Clarismundo Fornari, 915, Engordadouro,  - SP, 13214-660, Brasil'],
['Swift', -22.9310774, -47.0381773, 'Av Jorge Tibiriça, 551, Swift,  - SP, 13096-550, Brasil'],
['CROSSLIFEJANAUBA', -15.8163678, -43.3036, 'Av Manoel Athayde, 1060, Saudade,  - MG, 39445-281, Brasil'],
['PIRITUBA', -23.4926145, -46.7103305, 'Rua Custódio de Araújo, 80, VILA PEREIRA CERCA,  - SP, 02932-050, Brasil'],
['SF', -19.9442866, -43.9787316, 'Rua Maquiné, 580, Salgado Filho,  - MG, 30550-176, Brasil'],
[Mogi Guaçu', -22.3421956, -46.9482555, 'Avenida Bandeirantes, 1890, Ypê IV,  - SP, 13846-010, Brasil'],
['Nova Gerty', -23.6392394, -46.5665469, 'Rua Nelly Pellegrino, 707, Nova Gerty,  - SP, 09580-140, Brasil'],
['Terramérica', -22.768215, -47.356709, 'Av. Padre Oswaldo Vieira de Andrade, 569, Terramérica,  - SP, 13468-821, Brasil'],
['LIfe Mogi', -23.5184754, -46.1741309, 'Rua Adriano Cezar Pinto, 83, Socorro,  - SP, 08780-590, Brasil'],
['varzea centro', -23.2131507, -46.8458156, 'av jose rabelo portela, 276, jd maria de fatima,  - SP, 13220-520, Brasil'],
['Saguaçu Joinville', -26.2791381, -48.8460482, 'Rua Aluísio Pires Condeixa, 2700, Saguaçu,  - SC, 89221-008, Brasil'],
['ESCOLA DE DANCA E CONDICIONAMENTO FISICO RLUB', -23.7359969, -46.6947068, 'Rua Leri Santos, 194, Parque America,  - SP, 04822-290, Brasil'],
['BARÃO', -21.1433681, -47.9829966, 'Rua Barao do Rio Branco, 2064, Centro,  - SP, 14160-570, Brasil'],
['Life Autódromo', -23.695804, -46.6923545, 'av joao paulo da silva, 635, vila da paz,  - SP, 04777-020, Brasil'],
['Life Conceição', -23.6372361, -46.6401292, 'Praça Barao de Japura, 85, Vila Guarani,  - SP, 04313-170, Brasil'],
['TESTE', -23.1848975, -46.9710744, 'Rua Chiara Lubich,, 371, Jardim Ermida I,  - SP, 13212-117, Brasil'],
['RJ ANIL', -22.9568606, -43.3464518, 'Estrada do Engenho dagua, 1375, Anil,  - RJ, 22765-240, Brasil'],
['JARDIM DOM JOSÉ', -23.676669, -46.800363, 'Avenida Jundia, 374, Jardim Dom José,  - SP, 06824-010, Brasil'],
['Guarulhos', -23.3992557, -46.398908, 'Estrada Acácio Antônio Batista, 898, Bonsucesso,  - SP, 07175-080, Brasil'],
['Aclimação', -23.5800915, -46.6242578, 'Av. Lins de Vasconcelos, 1887, Aclimação,  - SP, 01537-001, Brasil'],
['LEPORACE', -20.4965275, -47.4218309, 'Av Abrão brickimam, 1651, LEPORACE,  - SP, 14407-010, Brasil'],
['Bonfiglioli SP', -23.5778294, -46.7438786, 'Av: Eng Heitor Ant. Eiras Garcia, 868, Jd Bonfiglioli,  - SP, 05588-001, Brasil'],
['Maracanã Litoral Paulista- Baixada Santista', -24.0375914, -46.5095634, 'Av. Presidente keneddy, 10.563, MARACANÃ,  - SP, 11705-755, Brasil'],
['mascote', -23.6431095, -46.6662527, 'Rua Palestina, 48, vila Mascote,  - SP, 04362-030, Brasil'],
['=Taguatinga Sul', -15.8107481, -48.065751, 'Qsa 12, loja 08, comercial sul, s/n, Taguatinga,  - DF, 72015-12, Brasil'],
['=VILA ISABE', -22.9188801, -43.2515651, 'Rua Teodoro da Silva, 675, Vila Isabel,  - RJ, 20560-002, Brasil'],
['=Angelica', -20.664223, -43.7866209, 'Rua Coronel Licinio Dutra, 263, Angelica,  - MG, 36400-031, Brasil'],
['=SÃO ROQUE', -29.1390673, -51.5226835, 'Tr JOSÉ RAMPANELLI, 275, SÃO ROQUE,  - RS, 95708-490, Brasil'],
['=Vila Leopoldina', -23.527816, -46.7334758, 'Av. Imperatriz Leopoldina, 609, Vila Leopoldina,  - SP, 05305-011, Brasil']
        ];

        function initMap() {

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-84.568808, -100.418683);

            var options = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                zoom: 2
            });

            marker.setPosition(latlng);

            setMarkers(map,locations);

            setMarkers(map,locations2);

        }

        function setMarkers(map,locations){

            var marker, i

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

                var loan = locations[i][0]
                var lat = locations[i][1]
                var long = locations[i][2]
                var add =  locations[i][3]

                latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                    map: map,
                    title: loan,
                    position: latlngset,
                    icon: image
                });

                // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
                // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
                for (var city in locations) {
                  // Add the circle for this city to the map.
                  var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    zoom: 2,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                    radius: 750,
                    strokeColor: "#818c99",
                    fillColor: "#ffffff",
                    fillOpacity: 0.70
                  });
                }

                for (var city in locations2) {
                  // Add the circle for this city to the map.
                  var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    zoom: 2,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                    radius: 750,
                    strokeColor: "#229A1F",
                    fillColor: "#49DA45",
                    fillOpacity: 0.50
                  });
                }

                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())

                var content = "<h5>" + loan + '</h5>' + "<strong>Endereço:</strong> " + add;

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    };
                })(marker,content,infowindow));

            }

        }

        function carregarNoMapa(endereco) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': endereco + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {

                        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                        $('#txtEndereco').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                        $('#txtLatitude').val(latitude);
                        $('#txtLongitude').val(longitude);

                        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        marker.setPosition(location);
                        map.setCenter(location);
                        map.setZoom(16);
                        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#mapa").offset().top}, 800);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function excluirReserva(codigo) {
            if(confirm('Excluir reserva permanentemente?')){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: "_ajax/reservar-excluir.php",
                    data: {codigo: codigo},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#returnResponse').html(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        $("#btnEndereco").click(function() {
            if($(this).val() != "")
                carregarNoMapa($("#txtEndereco").val());
                $("#txtEnderecoReserva").val($("#txtEndereco").val());
                $("#btnSalvarReserva").show();
                $("#reservaLabel").show();
                $("#reservaLabel2").show();
        });

        $("#txtEndereco").blur(function() {
            if($(this).val() != "")
                carregarNoMapa($(this).val());

        });

        $("#txtEndereco").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
                    response($.map(results, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.formatted_address,
                            value: item.formatted_address,
                            latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                            longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                        }
                    }));
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#txtLatitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
                $("#txtLongitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
                $("#txtEnderecoReserva").val(ui.item.label);
                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
                marker.setPosition(location);
                map.setCenter(location);
                map.setZoom(16);
                $("#btnSalvarReserva").show();
                $("#reservaLabel").show();
                $("#reservaLabel2").show();
            }
        });

        /*$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#mapa").offset().top}, 800);*/

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').attr('onload', 'initMap();');

            $("#numeroUnidades").html('112 UNIDADES');

            $("#btnSalvarReserva").on('click', function(){

                var endereco = $("#txtEnderecoReserva").val();
                var latitude = $("#txtLongitude").val();
                var longitude = $("#txtLatitude").val();
                var reservaNome = $("#reserva_nome").val();
                var registro = $("#reserva_registro").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: "_ajax/reservar-endereco.php",
                    data: {endereco : endereco, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, nome: reservaNome, registro: registro},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#returnResponse').html(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });

            });

        });

  </script>
```

Comment: disponibiliza algum código para possamos ajudar

Comment: mas basicamente calculas a distância entre os centros dos círculos, se for menor que a soma do raio dos dois círculos, há intersecção .

Comment: @13dev disponibilizei,

Comment: O código inclui a pesquisa de endereço, o mapa, os marcadores e o código de integração da API

Comment: @13dev mas é essa a minha dificuldade, não sei fazer a intersecção, pesquisei a fio na documentação, e não encontrei sobre isso.

Comment: já faço um exemplo, aguarda.

Comment: Blza, gratidão.

Comment: @13dev O exemplo abaixo está com erro na função hasIntersections(); Uncaught TypeError: circle0.getCenter is not a function, aparece apenas o primeiro marcador, aí exibe o erro e para o for();

Answer (score -1):

Usa estas funções para converter para radianos, obter a distancia e verificar se há interseção:

```
// Esta função vai converter graus para radianos
Number.prototype.toRadians = function() {
    return this * (Math.PI / 180.0);
};

function distance(lat0, long0, lat1, long1){

    // converter graus para radianos
    var rlat0 = lat0.toRadians();
    var rlong0 = long0.toRadians();
    var rlat1 = lat1.toRadians();
    var rlong1 = long1.toRadians();

    // calcular as diferenças para latitude e longitude (os deltas)
    var deltaLat = (rlat1-rlat0);
    var deltaLong = (rlong1-rlong0);

    // calcular a fórmula de uso grande haversine para calcular a distância do grande círculo entre dois pontos
    var a = Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLat / 2), 2) + Math.pow( Math.sin(deltaLong / 2), 2) * Math.cos(rlat0) * Math.cos(rlat1);  

    // multiplica pelo raio do grande círculo (raio médio da terra em metros)
    return (2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))) * 6378137;
}

function hasIntersections(circle0,circle1){
    var center0 = circle0.getCenter();
    var center1 = circle1.getCenter();

    var maxDist = circle0.getRadius()+circle1.getRadius();
    var actualDist = distance(center0.lat(),center0.lng(),center1.lat(),center1.lng());

    return maxDist>=actualDist;
}
```

Agora é so aplicares ao teu caso, guardas todos os círculos em **arrays**, e percorres esses mesmos e verificas se há interseção (exemplo não testado):

```
function setMarkers(map,locations){
//[....]

var circles = [];
var circles2 = [];
// Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
// Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
for (var city in locations) {
  // Add the circle for this city to the map.
  var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    radius: 750,
    strokeColor: "#818c99",
    fillColor: "#ffffff",
    fillOpacity: 0.70
  });
  //Adicionar circulo ao array
  circles.push(cityCircle);
}

for (var city in locations2) {
  // Add the circle for this city to the map.
  var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    radius: 750,
    strokeColor: "#229A1F",
    fillColor: "#49DA45",
    fillOpacity: 0.50
  });

  //Adicionar circulo ao array
  circles2.push(cityCircle);
}

//Percorrer todos os circlos
for (var circle1 in circles) {
    for (var circle2 in circles2) {
        //Faz a verificação se os circulos tocam-se
        // Aqui alteras a cor desejada
        console.log(hasIntersections(circle1, circle2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou adaptar no código, já posto o que aconteceu.

Comment: @EliseuB. dá uma olhadela https://stackoverflow.com/q/19772441/5244258